# ¿como hacer focus a un textfield y ocultar el teclado con flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

necesito hacer focus a un textfield especifico pero no logro ocultar el teclado, se debe de ocultar que dejar ver una información que aparece después de dar enter al textfield, pero al hacer focus no logro que se oculte,¿ de que forma podría lograrlo?

Comment: Puedes agregar el código que intentaste para poder ayudarte? trata de reducir el problema , agrega un ejemplo sencilllo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estaría bien mirar tu código, pero intuyo que con esto será suficiente:

Pon un GestureDetector en el Scaffold por ejemplo (o el widget que contenga como hijo el textField) y en el onTab añades las siguientes lineas a continuación:

```
Scaffold(
    body: GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        final FocusScopeNode focus = FocusScope.of(context);
         if (!focus.hasPrimaryFocus && focus.hasFocus) {
            FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus.unfocus();
         }
      },
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          CustomScrollView(
            slivers: [
              _loginHeader(),
              _loginBody(context),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    ))
```

En mi caso el textField lo tengo en el body. Lo que te quiero decir con esto es que el GestureDetector lo pongas en lo más alto de la página donde tengas los textField y con el FocusManager ocultas el teclado. Espero haberte ayudado. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Para ocultar el teclado puedes utilizar el siguiente fragmento de código, dentro un `onTap()` o un `onPressed()` ya sea de un botón o un GestureDetector, si tu objetivo  es cerrar el teclado si el usuario presiona fuera del campo de texto, puedes usar como Widget padre el `GestureDetector`

```
FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);
   if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus) {
       currentFocus.unfocus();
   }
```

```
    Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Title Example"),
      ),
      body: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);
          if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus) {
            currentFocus.unfocus();
          }
        },
        child: Column(children: [
          searchInput(context),
          const Expanded(child: ListClients())
        ]),
      ),
    )
```

Para hacer un focus automático dentro un texto puedes usar el atributo `autofocus:true` del `TextFormField` y si son varios textForms puedes utilizar el `textInputAction:TextInputAction.next` para que el focus salte al siguiente textForm.

Para hacer un uso mas funcional del focus puedes utilizar `FocusNode` y asignarlo al textForm para mas información consulte la documentación
[Focus and text fields](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/forms/focus)